# Split a list of tuples into Multiple items which are close to each other

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples

```
[(305, 312),  (313, 319),  (320, 323),  (324, 331),  (332, 336),  (337, 342),  (343, 350),  (351, 362),  (511, 520),  (928, 932),  (933, 942),  (943, 953),  (954, 957),  (958, 961),  (962, 967),  (968, 973),  (974, 979),  (980, 986),  (987, 991),  (992,  1001),  (1002, 1008),  (1009, 1011),  (1012, 1019),  (1020, 1024),  (1025, 1030),  (1031, 1033),  (1034, 1037),  (1038, 1042),  (1043, 1053),  (1054, 1060),  (1061, 1066),  (1067, 1082),  (1083, 1085),  (1086, 1090),  (1091, 1095),  (1096, 1105),  (1106, 1113),  (1114, 1116),  (1117, 1123),  (1124, 1127),  (1128, 1134),  (1135, 1143),  (1144, 1146),  (1147, 1160),  (1161, 1165),  (1166, 1170),  (1171, 1183),  (6385, 6394)]
```

How to separate this into multiple list of tuples each of which contain values which have last value of a tuple and first value of another separated by a single value.

**Expected Output**

```
[(305, 312),  (313, 319),  (320, 323),  (324, 331),  (332, 336),  (337, 342),  (343, 350),  (351, 362)]
[(511, 520)]
[(928, 932),  (933, 942),  (943, 953),  (954, 957),  (958, 961),  (962, 967),  (968, 973),  (974, 979),  (980, 986),  (987, 991),  (992,  1001),  (1002, 1008),  (1009, 1011),  (1012, 1019),  (1020, 1024),  (1025, 1030),  (1031, 1033),  (1034, 1037),  (1038, 1042),  (1043, 1053),  (1054, 1060),  (1061, 1066),  (1067, 1082),  (1083, 1085),  (1086, 1090),  (1091, 1095),  (1096, 1105),  (1106, 1113),  (1114, 1116),  (1117, 1123),  (1124, 1127),  (1128, 1134),  (1135, 1143),  (1144, 1146),  (1147, 1160),  (1161, 1165),  (1166, 1170),  (1171, 1183)]
[(6385, 6394)]
```

I tried this way

```
i = 0
length = len(position)
while i<length:
    values = []
    if position[i+1][0] - position[i][1] == 1:
        values.append(position[i])
    print(values)
    i+=1
```

Comment: What have you tried.  StackOverflow doesn't do your homework for you.

Comment: I am working on it. Got into some infinite loop. I will post once I solve that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```py
lst = [(305, 312),  (313, 319),  (320, 323),  (324, 331),  (332, 336),  (337, 342),  (343, 350),  (351, 362),  (511, 520),  (928, 932),  (933, 942),  (943, 953),  (954, 957),  (958, 961),  (962, 967),  (968, 973),  (974, 979),  (980, 986),  (987, 991),  (992,  1001),  (1002, 1008),  (1009, 1011),  (1012, 1019),  (1020, 1024),  (1025, 1030),  (1031, 1033),  (1034, 1037),  (1038, 1042),  (1043, 1053),  (1054, 1060),  (1061, 1066),  (1067, 1082),  (1083, 1085),  (1086, 1090),  (1091, 1095),  (1096, 1105),  (1106, 1113),  (1114, 1116),  (1117, 1123),  (1124, 1127),  (1128, 1134),  (1135, 1143),  (1144, 1146),  (1147, 1160),  (1161, 1165),  (1166, 1170),  (1171, 1183),  (6385, 6394)]

new_lst = []
l = []
last = lst[0][1]
for f,e in lst:
    if f-last >1:
        new_lst.append(l)
        l = []
    last = e
    l.append((f,e))

if l:
    new_lst.append(l)

for a in new_lst:
    print(a)
```

OUTPUT

```py
[(305, 312), (313, 319), (320, 323), (324, 331), (332, 336), (337, 342), (343, 350), (351, 362)]
[(511, 520)]
[(928, 932), (933, 942), (943, 953), (954, 957), (958, 961), (962, 967), (968, 973), (974, 979), (980, 986), (987, 991), (992, 1001), (1002, 1008), (1009, 1011), (1012, 1019), (1020, 1024), (1025, 1030), (1031, 1033), (1034, 1037), (1038, 1042), (1043, 1053), (1054, 1060), (1061, 1066), (1067, 1082), (1083, 1085), (1086, 1090), (1091, 1095), (1096, 1105), (1106, 1113), (1114, 1116), (1117, 1123), (1124, 1127), (1128, 1134), (1135, 1143), (1144, 1146), (1147, 1160), (1161, 1165), (1166, 1170), (1171, 1183)]
[(6385, 6394)]
```

Comment: I didnt understand the logic of 150

Comment: @imhans4305 your list is split if the value is greater or equal to the `last value + 150`.

Comment: Yeah. But that specific number 150. What can happen if it is changed ?

Comment: @imhans4305 if you change the value then you list split with that difference. Try to change it to 10 or something other.

Comment: That 150 will work in this case alone right. For any different set of input this wont work.

Comment: @imhans4305 as you say you want to split the close items, But you do not say how close there need to be, Like  100 and 200 are close or not, and 100 and 300 are close or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244918/discussion-between-imhans4305-and-sharim-iqbal).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
my_list = [(305, 312), (313, 319), (320, 323), (324, 331), (332, 336), (337, 342), (343, 350), (351, 362), (511, 520), (928, 932), (933, 942), (943, 953), (954, 957), (958, 961), (962, 967), (968, 973), (974, 979), (980, 986), (987, 991), (992, 1001), (1002, 1008), (1009, 1011), (1012, 1019), (1020, 1024), (1025, 1030), (1031, 1033), (1034, 1037), (1038, 1042), (1043, 1053), (1054, 1060), (1061, 1066), (1067, 1082), (1083, 1085), (1086, 1090), (1091, 1095), (1096, 1105), (1106, 1113), (1114, 1116), (1117, 1123), (1124, 1127), (1128, 1134), (1135, 1143), (1144, 1146), (1147, 1160), (1161, 1165), (1166, 1170), (1171, 1183), (6385, 6394)]
out = [[]]
for (h,i), (j,k) in zip(my_list, my_list[1:]+[[None]*2]):
    # append to the last list in out
    out[-1].append((h,i))
    # add a new empty list to out if the difference between 
    # the last element in the current tuple and the first element in the next tuple 
    # is not 1 and we're not at the end of the list
    if i+1!=j and i != my_list[-1][-1]:
        out.append([])        
print(out)
[[(305, 312), (313, 319), (320, 323), (324, 331), (332, 336), (337, 342), (343, 350), (351, 362)], 
 [(511, 520)], 
 [(928, 932), (933, 942), (943, 953), (954, 957), (958, 961), (962, 967), (968, 973), (974, 979), (980, 986), (987, 991), (992, 1001), (1002, 1008), (1009, 1011), (1012, 1019), (1020, 1024), (1025, 1030), (1031, 1033), (1034, 1037), (1038, 1042), (1043, 1053), (1054, 1060), (1061, 1066), (1067, 1082), (1083, 1085), (1086, 1090), (1091, 1095), (1096, 1105), (1106, 1113), (1114, 1116), (1117, 1123), (1124, 1127), (1128, 1134), (1135, 1143), (1144, 1146), (1147, 1160), (1161, 1165), (1166, 1170), (1171, 1183)], 
 [(6385, 6394)]]
```